# Transaction to release ETH from contract not succeeding

Tags: solidity, truffle

I pasted my contract code below and have deployed to my testrpc. The whole purpose of this contract is to lock up ETH until a specified block number. After that block number is reached, it can be released using the "release".

To test, I sent 50 ETH to it from account `0xf17f52151EbEF6C7334FAD080c5704D77216b732`.

I have now exceeded the minimum block and want to call the "release" method to get my 50 ETH back into the same account. So I run this script:

```
HodlEthereum.deployed().then(function(contractInstance) {
  contractInstance.party({from:acct, gas:2000000}).then(function(v) {
    console.log(v)
  });
})
```

Unfortunately this is not working and I'm not sure why. I funded the txn with gas. The testrpc logs say "revert". Any clues?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract HodlEthereum {
    event Hodl(address indexed hodler, uint indexed amount);
    event Release(address indexed hodler, uint indexed amount);
    mapping (address => uint) public hodlers;
    uint constant targetTime = 8; // block num
    uint constant targetBlock = 8;

    function() payable {
        hodlers[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        Hodl(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function release() returns (bool success){
        require (block.number >= targetBlock && hodlers[msg.sender] > 0);
        uint value = hodlers[msg.sender];
        hodlers[msg.sender] = 0;
        msg.sender.transfer(value);
        Release(msg.sender, value);
    }

    function getBalance(address hodler) returns (uint balance){
      balance = hodlers[hodler];
    }
}
```